# Generalised letrec semantics for mutual recursion

Tags: recursion, type-systems, letrec

I'm new to system types and I was wondering how mutual recursion is defined through generalized
let rec x1=e1 ,....,xn=en in e .What has to be added in the "simple" letrec's semantics and evaluation rules and how is its syntactic sugar (using fix ) changed as well ?

[image: semantics rules]

[image: syntactic sugar]

Comment: This question is more appropriate for for https://cs.stackexchange.com/ I think. SO is for practical programming problems.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic and belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com/